# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php

This is my code.

```
  <?php

  $name = 'John Doe';
  echo 'My name is $name';
  echo "I am from $_COOKIE['mylocation']";
```

i got an error from this

```
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in : eval()'d code on line 3
```

if any one know about this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `'`:

```
<?php

  $name = 'John Doe';
  echo 'My name is $name';
  echo "I am from $_COOKIE[mylocation]";
```

Beware of [XSS vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)!

Answer (score 1):

The variables should not be enclosed in the quotes..It should be concatenated using `.` after closing the quotes

Close the  single quotes in `echo` before `$name` as well as `$_COOKIE['mylocation']`

```
 <?php

  $name = 'John Doe';
  echo 'My name is'.$name;
  echo "I am from". $_COOKIE['mylocation'];
```